# Django Admin upload new models to current

Tags: python, django, django-admin

recently started programming on django, still trying to understand it.
Anyway, i've been assigned to maintain a website/webapp (i don't know how to call it) made in django, as part of the work produce modifies as client needs.

Everything was fine untill the modifies are about the current setup.

I've made a lot of tries but can't understand why adding new models to the project is not working.

The project **Listings** contains the following models:

- Listing(Immobili)
- Photo
- Owner(Proprietario)
- Zone(Zona)

All the models are related to the Listing.
[Current Admin form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OHo.png)

```
Here a code example (admin.py):

@admin.register(models.Photo)
class PhotoInline(admin.TabularInline):
      ....

@admin.register(models.Listing)
class ListingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       ....

       inlines=[PhotoInline,...]
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to add the concept of **Video**, but easier than photo, so i've made a model **Video** as follow:

```
models.py:

class Video(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(...)
    video_name = models.CharField(...)
    video_url = models.CharField(...)

admin.py:

class VideoInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = models.Video    
      extra = 1

@admin.register(models.Listing)
class ListingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       ....

       inlines=[PhotoInline,VideoInline...]
```

After those modifies i've launch the

```
python manage.py makemigrations listings
python manage.py migrate listings
```

No output error, and the page was working as before.

Any advice to upload this modify?

Thanks to anyone that will just read the question.

Comment: What i can tell you is you need a ```FileField()``` somewhere in your ```Video``` modal you may need to do something like ```video = FileField()``` add some neccessay ```arguments``` and there you will go; Add you will need to configure your ```upload``` directory, I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway i'm trying to stay in a easier level, what i'd like to achieve is to have a form where i can upload just the URL of a video like a youtube video.